# "type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte"

Tags: java, casting, int, byte, overloading

new to Java and so far struggling a lot.. tried all day to fix this error yesterday and to no avail... any help will be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Date;
class Proj06{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Random generator = null;
    if(args.length != 0){
      generator = new Random(Long.parseLong(args[0]));
    }else{
      generator = new Random(new Date().getTime());
    };
    
    //Get and save positive random number of type int.
    int valA = Math.abs((generator.nextInt()))/67000 + 1024;
    
    Proj06Runner obj = new Proj06Runner();

    String valB = obj.run("certificaton");
    String valC = obj.run(1,"name");
    byte valD =   obj.run(valA);

    //Print the original random integer
    System.out.println(valA);
    
    //Print the three values returned from the three calls
    // to the run method.
    System.out.println(valB);
    System.out.println(valC);
    System.out.println(valD);
    
    //Print the original random integer after casting it
    // down to type byte.
    //System.out.println((byte)valA);

  }//end main

public class Proj06Runner extends Proj06{
  public int run(int valA){
    return valA;
  }
  public String run(String valB){
    return "this works";
  }
  public String run(int i, String valC){
    return "this also works";
  }
//this does not work 
  public byte run(byte valD){
    return valD;
  }

}
```

I can't change anything in main..i know there's an error with how valA is an int but i'm assigning it to a byte variable

Comment: Is the error message not clear to you? You cannot convert an `int` to a `byte`. But you try it e.g. in `byte valD =   obj.run(valA);` and the compiler says "nope".

Comment: it is clear but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: `valD` should be an `int`

Comment: my professor wrote the main code and i cannot change byte valD =   obj.run(valA);

Comment: Then `run (int valA)` should return a `byte`. Ask your professor to explain it to you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Proj06Runner class has these two methods:

```
  public int run(int valA){
    return valA;
  }
  public byte run(byte valD){
    return valD;
  }
```

First one takes an `int` and returns an `int`. The second one takes a `byte` and returns a `byte`. You are calling the first one. I suspect you expected to call the second one, but that will not work because the `main` method is passing an `int` as the parameter.

One way to fix the compiler error is to "merge" these two methods into one method that takes an `int` and returns a `byte`. For example:

```
  public byte run(int valD){
    return (byte) valD;
  }
```

Comment: thank you for being nice. i had tried that initially but i kept the first method in which it wouldn't work because of duplicate method but once i deleted the first method it worked. thank you